# Cómo se puede usar OnsenUI sin necesidad de internet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Estoy creando una aplicación mediante tecnologías web, utilizo PhoneGap y OnsenUi, para poder usar los componentes de Onsen utilizo la CDN de la página:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.min.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
```

Hay manera de poder usar los componentes de Onsen de manera local?, sin necesidad de utilizar el CDN para que la aplicación no requiera conexión a internet?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes descargar los componentes, basta que copies esos links y vayas a un navegador, se te va a abrir el source del código, puedes copiar el texto y guardarlo en un file con la misma extensión del link .min.css por ejemplo, los guardas dentro de tu proyecto y cambias el link, no más al de internet si no a los que guardaste